# Terraform cloudwatch_log_metric_filter - technique to filter to specific stream prefix?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Asking the question to make sure I'm not missing out on something. When using Terraform's cloudwatch_log_metric_filter, and you have a loggroup that has many streams, is there a way to filter to a specific log stream prefix?

Thanks!

Reference:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_log_metric_filter

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "yada" {
  name           = "MyAppAccessCount"
  pattern        = "_special_logstream_prefix_filter_pattern_???"
  log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.dada.name

  metric_transformation {
    name      = "EventCount"
    namespace = "YourNamespace"
    value     = "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that functionality is doable with Cloudwatch Logs metric filters. If you think otherwise can you share a link to AWS documentation about how it's configured without Terraform please?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to filter to a specific log stream prefix?

No. You are doing it correctly in your code as the filter functionality can be applied at the log group level, and not the log stream level.